# Is it safe to cook in a clean Teflon pot if the inside bottom has blistered and peeled from exposure to high heat?

Tags: food-safety, teflon

Is it safe to cook in a Teflon pot that has blistered and peeled and produced fumes from previously being heated too high? This is what the bottom of the pot looks like

[image]

Comment: From [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2015/jan/25/are-my-non-stick-pans-a-health-hazard-teflon): "If you have flaking pans, you could swallow a chip of Teflon, and while it might be medically OK, why would you want to? Throw them away. The rest are fine to keep."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We toss them out when they start doing this. They'll just keep peeling from here on out and we try to be healthy with our cooking. No way do we want to eat teflon. We actually replaced all of our pots and pans for ceramic coated. Hope to see if they last a little longer.

Comment: Teflon is very inert, and food safe etc. Yes you don't want to eat it as it's not food, but it wont harm you. Some reports say fumes from overheated Teflon may be dangerous? The ceramic coating will come off too! So will seasoned (polymerised) oil, that's a form of plastic, but we end up eating shards of it all the time

Comment: Lead paint was safe until 1974.

Comment: The coating is not lead based? Shards of Teflon come off pans in good condition, this is an acceptable part of any pans design

Comment: I don't use Teflon anymore so no need to prove your point to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just treat it as a regular metal pan now, and season it with oil and high heat

Though, first you have to remove all the flaked coating with a hard metal scourer. This may prove difficult!

Have done this to a few pans, and they work well as plain metal pans. Somewhat easier to use that plain steel, as they are aluminium and therefore lighter on the hand